# How to avoid multiple 401 when using Windows authentication on HTTP.sys

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, http.sys, http-negotiate

I have a Web API which uses .NET core 2.2 and HTTP.Sys. I've setup Windows authentication and I can see the 401 WWW-Negotiate challenge followed by 200 when the user is authorized.

Now I've performed the same request several times but I see the challenge is happening for every request, slowing down the system and affecting performance.
My sample client:

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Proxy = new WebProxy
    {
        Address = new Uri("http://HOSTNAME:8888"),
    }
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
{

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://HOSTNAME:5000/");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/user").Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

I read that for IIS it seems you can use `authPersistNonNTLM=true` [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2014/02/11/iis-how-to-reduce-multiple-authentication-or-multiple-401-while-using-kerberos-for-authentication/), but I couldn't fine a similar setting for pure HTTP.sys. any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any similar option in the [`HttpSysOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.httpsysoptions) class (the options you pass to HTTP.sys).

What might help is to not dispose your `HttpClient` (don't use `using` on it). `HttpClient` is thread-safe and is intended to be reused. In fact, you should keep a `static` reference to it and reuse it. There is a lengthy discussion of why [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), but in short: if you don't, it won't reuse connections.

That might have something to do with why you're seeing this. But if that doesn't resolve it, monitor the traffic and see if the authentication details are being sent by the client on the first request. They should be, since you set `UseDefaultCredentials`, but if not, then that's your problem.

*Update:* You can also try setting the [`PreAuthenticate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.preauthenticate) property on your `HttpClientHandler`:

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    Proxy = new WebProxy
    {
        Address = new Uri("http://HOSTNAME:8888"),
    }
};
```

According to the documentation, after the first successful authentication, it will send the credentials on all following requests to the same hosts, without waiting for a 401 challenge.

Comment: tried without disposing an the result is the same. BTW I am not disposing the client for each request, the same client is used for all 10 requests.

Comment: I don't see any similar option to `authPersistNonNTLM`, so I'm not sure if that's possible. But if the client is sending credentials on the first request, then you still shouldn't get a 401. If you monitor the traffic, do you see the `Authorization` header sent on the first request?

Comment: it seems to be a restriction in HTTP.SYS: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13634

Comment: I just updated my answer. I happened to stumble across the `PreAuthenticate` property today. It might help you here.